# Como passar um arquivo de inteiros para um vetor em C?

Tags: c, classificação

Estou com um problema na hora de passar os dados do meu arquivo (números inteiros) para o vetor.

O propósito do programa abaixo é verificar a performance dos algoritmos de ordenação (Mergesort, Bubble Sort, QuickSort) mas sempre que ponho um número de dados acima de 42, o programa trava dá *crash*.

Abaixo estão os algoritmos para gerar o arquivo.txt e o outro para ordenar o vetor, respectivamente.

PS: O código está meio bagunçado, perdão.

Código gerador do TXT:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main (void)
    {
        FILE *x;
        x = fopen("ex.txt","wt");
        if(x == NULL)
        {
            printf("Erro");
            return(-1);
        }
        int i,n,y;
        printf("Quantos nums serao gerados? ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        system("cls");
        clock_t inicio = clock(); 
        for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
            y= (rand()%100);    
            fprintf(x,"%d\n", y);
            //printf("%d\n",y);
        }    
        fclose(x);
        clock_t fim = clock();
        double gasto = difftime(fim,inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  
        printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);
        return(0);
    }
```

Código ordenador do vetor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int qtd;                    
void quicksort(int *P, int tam);
void mergesort(int p1[],int i,int j);
void merge(int p2[],int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2);

void mergesort(int p1[],int i,int j)
{
    clock_t inicio = clock();
    int meio;     
    if(i<j)
    {
        meio=(i+j)/2;
        mergesort(p1,i,meio);       
        mergesort(p1,meio+1,j);    
        merge(p1,i,meio,meio+1,j);
    }
    clock_t fim = clock();
    double gasto = difftime(fim,inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  
    printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);
}

void merge(int p2[],int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2)
{
    int aux[qtd];
    int i,j,k;
    i=i1; 
    j=i2; 
    k=0;   
    while(i<=j1 && j<=j2)
    {
        if(p2[i]<p2[j])
            aux[k++]=p2[i++];
        else
            aux[k++]=p2[j++];
    }  
    while(i<=j1)
        aux[k++]=p2[i++];        
    while(j<=j2) 
        aux[k++]=p2[j++];
    for(i=i1,j=0;i<=j2;i++,j++)
        p2[i]=aux[j];
}

void quicksort(int *P, int tam) {
    clock_t inicio = clock(); 
    if (tam < 2) {
        return;
    }
    int pivo = P[tam/2];
    int i3, j3;
    for (i3 = 0, j3 = tam - 1; ; i3++, j3--) {
        while (P[i3] < pivo){
            i3++;
        }
        while (P[j3] > pivo){
            j3--;
        }
        if (i3 >= j3) {
            break;
        }
        int aux2 = P[i3];
        P[i3] = P[j3];
        P[j3] = aux2;
    }
    quicksort(P, i3);
    quicksort(P + i3, tam - i3);
    clock_t fim = clock();
    double gasto = difftime(fim,inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  
    printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);
}

int main () {

    FILE *x;   
    char c,arq[100];
    int i,y,op,co;
    int p[qtd]; 

    printf("Digite o nome do arquivo: ");
    gets(arq);
    system("cls");

    x = fopen(arq,"r");
    for (c = getc(x); c != EOF; c = getc(x))
        if (c == '\n') 
            qtd = qtd + 1;
    fclose(x);
    x = fopen(arq,"r");        

    fseek(x, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(x)){
        for(i=0;i<qtd;i++){
            fscanf(x,"%d",&y);
            p[i]=y;
        }
    }

    fclose(x);  
    clock_t inicio = clock();

    do{
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf("1. Bubblesort\n");
        printf("2. Mergesort\n");
        printf("3. Quicksort\n");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        system("cls");
        clock_t fim = clock();
        double gasto = difftime(fim,inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  

        switch(op){    
        case 1:
            int aux, k, j;          
            for(k=qtd-2;k>=0;k--){
              for(j=0;j<=k;j++){
                if(p[j]>p[j+1] ){
                   aux=p[j];
                   p[j]=p[j+1];
                   p[j+1]=aux;
                }
              }
            }       
            printf("Vetor ordenado: \n");
            for(k=0;k<qtd;k++){
                printf("%d\n",p[k]);
            } 
            printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);       
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            return 0;                         
            break;
        case 2:
            mergesort(p,0,qtd-1);   
            printf("\nVetor Ordenado: \n");
            for(i=0;i<qtd;i++){
                printf("%d\n",p[i]);
            }
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            return 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            quicksort(p,qtd);
            printf("Vetor ordenado: \n");
            for (co = 0; co < qtd; co++) {
                printf("%d\n", p[co]);
            }                       
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Entrada invalida!\n");
            printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);     
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            return 0;
            break;
        }

    }while(op != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por que você tem `return 0;` e logo em seguida `break;`?

Comment: em qual parte da erro? na geração do arquivo? ao tentar ler o arquivo? ao tentar ordenar o array?

Comment: Testei a tua geração de números randômicos e ela está ok.

Comment: Uma dica, se tens instruções repetidas em todos os cases do teu switch, coloca essas instruções apenas uma vez fora do swith.

Comment: Teu maior problema no código é que usas a variável global qtd e usas ela para determinar o tamanho do vetor. Podes declarar o vetor após saberes qual a quantidade do mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema da sua pergunta é causado por esta linha, dentro da função main:

```
int p[qtd];
```

A questão é que C não pode calcular dinamicamente o tamanho de vetores - você tem que colocar um tamanho fixo para compilar o programa. No caso você ainda tenta usar o valor de qtd *ANTES* de calcular o seu valor, então mesmo que fosse uma linguagem dinâmica como Javascript, o valor de "qtd" não estaria definido nessa declaração. O fato é que o compilador simplesmente cria um vetor de tamanho desconhecido nessa declaração - e, por acaso, quando você excede 42 números no vetor, a coisa explode. Mas poderia estar acontecendo com 2 números, ou com 10000. Outra resposta aqui sugere mudar a declaração do `p` para um ponto em que `qtd` está definido  - mas isso não funciona em C - ele apenas deu sorte do vetor alocado ser maior lá. O valor em declarações de declaração do tipo `int p[NUMERO]` é usado quando o programa é compilado, e já está fixo quando ele é executado.

A forma correta de lidar com isso é com alocação dinâmica de memória: você declara sua variável `p` apenas como um vetor de inteiros:

```
int p[];
```

(ou `int *p;` - vai ser a mesma coisa) Depois de conhecer a quantidade de elementos no vetor, você aloca uma região na memória chamando `malloc`. Testa se o retorno de malloc não é `NULL`. (Em geral, respostas aqui no S.O. pulam esse teste, mas ele é vital em sistemas que vão pra produção e deve fazer parte do modo de pensar de qualquer um que programe em C).

`malloc` está definida em "stdlib.h", que já foi incluido, então depois de percorrer o arquivo e saber o valor de qtd, você pode adicionar essas linhas para reservar espaço para os seus dados:

```
...
int qtd;
int *p;
// parte do programa para saber o valor de qtd
...
p = malloc(sizeof(int) * qtd);
if (p == NULL) {
    printf("Falha ao alocar memória.\n");
    exit(1);
}
// Pode continuar a execução do seu codigo original aqui
...
```

Isso vai eliminar o seu erro - não chequei outros problemas. Algumas dicas no entanto:

Os PCs modernos executam bilhões de operações por segundo - e a linguagem C usa esse potencial na velocidade máxima. Isso significa que ordenar vetores com 100 números é algo que vai ser feito em pouquissímos milisegundos, talvez menos de 1. Assimq ue o programa funcionar, pode aumentar os números usados e tamanho do arquivo para valroe sbem melhores - da ordem de 100000 números - aí talvez você passe a ver alguma diferença.

Outra coisa, evite usar o a chamada "system": isso executa todo UM OUTRO programa fora do seu programa, e não é parte da linguagem C. Em algum ponto professores de faculdade no Brasil começaram a usar `system("pause");` para que os alunos que não sabiam usar o terminal pudessem olhar a saída de seus programas, mas essa prática é horrível.
Para esperar uma tecla, você pode usar o `gets()` mesmo (mas a tecla tem que ser o ENTER) - e para apagar a tela, imprima uma série de "\n"s - (isso é o que o CLS faz - só que é um outro programa inteiro só para fazer isso): `for (int i=0; i< 80; i++) printf("\r\n");` .

Usar o `system` para essas coisas, além dos recursos da máquina (que ainda vão parecer instantâneos em código desse tipo, apesar de serem da ordem de 100 mil a 1 milhão de vezes mais memória e instruções executados), torna o seu programa específico para o windows - enquanto que sem ele, o mesmo programa pode funcionar no Mac, Linux, em servidores Unix na internet, etc...

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Segue o teu código alterado com algumas sugestões:

```
void quicksort(int *P, int tam);
void mergesort(int p1[],int i, int j);
void merge(int p2[],int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2);

void mergesort(int p1[],int i, int j)
{
    clock_t inicio = clock();
    int meio;     
    if(i<j)
    {
        meio=(i+j)/2;
        mergesort(p1,i,meio);       
        mergesort(p1,meio+1,j);    
        merge(p1,i,meio,meio+1,j);
    }
    clock_t fim = clock();
    double gasto = difftime(fim,inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  
    printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);
}

void merge(int p2[],int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2)
{
    int aux[j2];
    int i,j,k;
    i=i1; 
    j=i2; 
    k=0;   
    while(i<=j1 && j<=j2)
    {
        if(p2[i]<p2[j])
            aux[k++]=p2[i++];
        else
            aux[k++]=p2[j++];
    }  
    while(i<=j1)
        aux[k++]=p2[i++];        
    while(j<=j2) 
        aux[k++]=p2[j++];
    for(i=i1,j=0;i<=j2;i++,j++)
        p2[i]=aux[j];
}

void quicksort(int *P, int tam) {
    clock_t inicio = clock(); 
    if (tam < 2) {
        return;
    }
    int pivo = P[tam/2];
    int i3, j3;
    for (i3 = 0, j3 = tam - 1; ; i3++, j3--) {
        while (P[i3] < pivo){
            i3++;
        }
        while (P[j3] > pivo){
            j3--;
        }
        if (i3 >= j3) {
            break;
        }
        int aux2 = P[i3];
        P[i3] = P[j3];
        P[j3] = aux2;
    }
    quicksort(P, i3);
    quicksort(P + i3, tam - i3);
    clock_t fim = clock();
    double gasto = difftime(fim,inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  
    printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);
}

int main () {

    FILE *x;   
    char c,arq[100];
    int i,op,co;    
    int qtd; //não é uma boa prática o uso de variáveis globais                    

    printf("Digite o nome do arquivo: ");
    scanf("%s", arq);//alterei para não usar fgets
    system("cls");

    x = fopen(arq,"r"); //deves sempre testar se não veio NULL o x
    for (c = getc(x); c != EOF; c = getc(x))
        if (c == '\n') 
            qtd = qtd + 1;
    fclose(x);

    int p[qtd]; 
    x = fopen(arq,"r"); //deveria testar se não é NULL o valor de x        
    rewind(x); //se o objetivo é apenas voltar ao início, usa o rewind

    while(x != NULL && !feof(x)){ //o for interno estava errado
          fscanf(x,"%d",&p[i]); //desta forma, ele irá ler todos
          i++;
    }

    fclose(x);  
    clock_t inicio = clock();

    do{
        printf("Menu\n");
        printf("1. Bubblesort\n");
        printf("2. Mergesort\n");
        printf("3. Quicksort\n");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        system("cls");
        clock_t fim = clock();
        double gasto = difftime(fim,inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;  
        int aux, k, j;    

        switch(op){    
        case 1:
            for(k=qtd-2;k>=0;k--){
              for(j=0;j<=k;j++){
                if(p[j]>p[j+1] ){
                   aux=p[j];
                   p[j]=p[j+1];
                   p[j+1]=aux;
                }
              }
            }       
            printf("Vetor ordenado: \n");
            for(k=0;k<qtd;k++){
                printf("%d\n",p[k]);
            } 
            printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);       
            break;
        case 2:
            mergesort(p,0,qtd-1);   
            printf("\nVetor Ordenado: \n");
            for(i=0;i<qtd;i++){
                printf("%d\n",p[i]);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            quicksort(p,qtd);
            printf("Vetor ordenado: \n");
            for (co = 0; co < qtd; co++) {
                printf("%d\n", p[co]);
            }                       
            break;
        default:
            printf("Entrada invalida!\n");
            printf("\ntempo gasto: %f segundos\n", gasto);                 
        } //retirei o return 0 de dentro do switch
        system("pause"); //aqui vão as instruções em comum dos cases
        system("cls");
    }while(op != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A declaração de vetores dinâmicos como `int p[qtd];` não funciona em C -  o seu programa funcionou por acaso. Nesses casos, o programador C é responsável por alocar sua própria memória em chamadas a `malloc` e similares.

Comment: Todas as vezes que usei até hoje funcionaram. Mas concordo contigo que a alocação dinâmica com a função malloc é a melhor solução. Só não quis complicar muito o código pra ele.